# How to solve $\frac{dv}{dt}=2a^2k-3akv-2kv^2$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Urgent help $\ddot\frown$

Hello everyone. I have the following equation
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=2a^2k-3akv-2kv^2$$

and I want to solve it to find the velocity $v(t)$.

How can this be solved? I can't think of an integrating factor since there is both a $v$ and a $v^2$.

Anyone? Thanks!

Comment: The differential equation is separable?

Comment: your equation is a Riccati equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation. One solution is given by $v(t)=-2a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the equation is separable:
$$\frac{dv}{2a^2k-3akv-2kv^2}=dt$$
Integrating both terms:
$$\int\frac{dv}{2a^2k-3akv-2kv^2}= \frac{\ln\frac{2a+v}{2v-a}}{5ak}=t+c$$
where $c$ is a constant (you can do the integral as a rational integral). Now you have to obtain $v$ as a function of $t$. For that:
$$\frac{2a+v}{2v-a}=e^{5akt+c}\to v(t)=\frac{a(2+e^{5akt+c})}{2e^{5akt+c}-1}$$

Comment: Thank you for the edition, Parcly. I changed accidentally the variables.

Comment: Thank you very much! @mannav

Comment: You're welcome!